# wpf custom control send brush like TemplateBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

hi i created a custom control for button but there is problem in send Brush
if you see down below i created before Radius and its work but the Brush is not.
Note: It would be better if I put a picture to show the errors, rather than putting the code directly

[image]

and here the source :

[image]

here new code :

```
public class WPFButton : ButtonBase
    {
        public CornerRadius Radius
        {
            get { return (CornerRadius)GetValue(RadiusProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RadiusProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Radius", typeof(CornerRadius), typeof(WPFButton), new PropertyMetadata(new CornerRadius(0)));

        public Brush MouseHoverColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(MouseHoverColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MouseHoverColorProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseHoverColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MouseHoverColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(WPFButton), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush()) );

        static WPFButton()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(WPFButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(WPFButton)));
        }
    }
```

Xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:WPFButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:WPFButton}">
                    <Border Name="Background" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding Radius}">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Background" Value="{TemplateBinding MouseHoverColor}">

                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                       
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Background" Value="#FF4792DC">

                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: `new PropertyMetadata(new Brush())` does not compile (as VS tells you), because Brush is an abstract class. Set `null` or `new SolidColorBrush()` as default value.

Comment: Or do not set any metadata at all.

Comment: Please do not post images of code.  Post the text itself

Comment: @Clemens There is still an error.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, there is no MouseHoverColorProperty member. Be aware that there is a naming convention for the identifier fields of dependency properties. The field for a dependency property `X` must be named `XProperty`. So change the name from `BrushProperty` to `MouseHoverColorProperty`.

Comment: @Clemens thanks mate, but there is new err when i start the application : System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Set property 'System.Windows.Setter.Value' threw an exception.' Line number '19' and line position '59'.' . See the new code i put it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the `{TemplateBinding}` syntax in a `Setter`. This should work:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Background"
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                Path=MouseHoverColor}">

    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

Comment: thank you very much mate, finally its work.